# Permissions to edit deployed files on amazon ec2 (beanstalk)

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have begun a deployment on amazon ec2 I have deployed my war file and putty(d) in sucessfully to the correct instance using SSH (I generated a key pair)

I am logging in as ec2-user (the default) but the file permissions I need access to are owned by tomcat7.

Any suggestions please on how to su in as tomcat7 (or even root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. I used **sudo su** and that did the trick!